# What removals need to be made in order to make this Graph a Tree?

Tags: graph-theory

there were some other questions with not many nodes/edges, however I am really stuck on this one;

$$G = (\{1, 2, . . . , 999\}, {(i, j) | 1 ≤ i < j ≤ 999}).$$

I thought at first I could just get rid of all the nodes except $(1,2),(2,3),...,(998,999)$; but I'm not sure how I can show what I've removed. There's also a similar question;

$$G = (\{1, 2, . . . , 999\}, {(i, j) | 1 ≤ i < j ≤ 999 ∧ i ≡9 j})$$

I think once I know how to do the first one, it'll be pretty similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the graph a tree that way. It would be represented by $$ G_1 = (\{1,2,\dots , 999\}, (i,i+1) | 1 \leq i < 999).$$ Another way I see is to notice that the first node is connected to every other node, and just write $$ G_2 = (\{1,2,\dots,999\}, (1,j) | 2 \leq j \leq 999)$$

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I also need to explicitly state what removals have been made as well.

Comment: Then you can say you removed all nodes $(i,j) | j \neq i+1$

Comment: I see now, thanks so much for your help.